# How to get data from UIDatePicker countDownTimer mode

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have UIDatePicker in countDownTimer mode on AlertController. And I want to save values, that user will choose when he press Set button, to variable. How and were can I do it?
My code now:

```
func showAlert() {
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 300)
    let pickerView = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 300))
    pickerView.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
    vc.view.addSubview(pickerView)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sleep Timer", message: "Please, choose hours and minutes", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can access the picker's *countDownDuration* property to get the seconds value.

It ranges between 0 to 86,340 seconds.

```swift
let seconds = pickerView.countDownDuration
```

---

For your required case, you have a lot of options. 2 of them are:

### Easier

```swift
    func showAlert() {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 300)
        let pickerView = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 300))
        pickerView.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
        //Your required line
        pickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onDurationChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        vc.view.addSubview(pickerView)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sleep Timer", message: "Please, choose hours and minutes", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc private func onDurationChanged(_ picker: UIDatePicker) {
        let seconds = picker.countDownDuration
        //Do something with duration
    }
```

### Cleaner way

You could just create a small VC for the picker selection and then you can separate the concerns better:

```swift
class PickerViewController: UIViewController {
    var duration: TimeInterval = 0
    
    let pickerView: UIDatePicker = {
        let picker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 300))
        picker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onDurationChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        return picker
    }()
    
    @objc private func onDurationChanged(_ picker: UIDatePicker) {
        duration = picker.countDownDuration
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func showAlert() {
        let vc = PickerViewController()
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250,height: 300)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sleep Timer", message: "Please, choose hours and minutes", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set", style: .default, handler: { action in
            let seconds = vc.duration
            //Do something.
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to convert it to a date, compared to the current date, you can simply do:
let targetDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(seconds)

Comment: At what point is .countDownDuration set? When does the user set the values or when does the Alert close?
And second, how I can get .countDownDuration outside showAlert function?

Comment: Edited answer to include 2 approaches for you. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you very much. But PickerView didn't show up on my Alert Controller. I added a line vc.view.addSubview(vc.pickerView). It works.

Comment: I got another problem. When I do as you wrote above, the var duration is always 0.0, but if I write let seconds = vc.pickerView.countDownDuration, then it works

Comment: What approach did you choose to implement?
It seems, from your question, that you chose the first. Yes, you have to access the countdown timer directly and pull out the timer value

Comment: No, I choose second and duration is always 0. So I had to implement this logic through the completion handler